# Going from a VWP to being an overstay and now applying for a B2 visa with the intent of switching it to a student visa

Tags: visas

4 years ago i entered the US under the VWP and ended up overstaying by an extra 30 days. On my second visit I was almost denied entry but they told me the next time I want to visit I'll need to apply for a B2 visa. My question is: the next time I apply for a B2 visa and get it, can I change it to a student visa once I arrive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Here's [Rutgers, The State University of New Jersey instructions](http://globalservices.rutgers.edu/forms/Application_for_Change_of_Status_to_F-1.pdf) on doing so. I am sure your F-1 "provider" will have similar.

Edit: Here's [USCIS](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/C2en.pdf) of the same. It lists the categories that are not eligible for a change and B1/B2 is not among them and says you need to file a Form I-539.